# How to fix getting a empty .txt file

Tags: java, android

I want to write on a .txt file which is in 
 /data/user/0/{your.package.name}/files/.txt in my application.

I used OutputStreamWriter for the writing purpose.

```java
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter=new  
OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput(fileName+".txt",context.MODE_PRIVATE));
outputStreamWriter.write((var+",").substring(0,1));
```

var is a string variable which is not null
but .txt file is empty after writing.

Comment: how is this android studio related?

Comment: someone already edited the tags / format... it's even more `java` than `android`.

Comment: I use android studio to develop this project

Answer (score 0):

You need to `.flush()` and then `.close()` the stream:

```
outputStreamWriter.flush();
outputStreamWriter.close();
```